# Wie kann man "alle 5 Tage" für einen medizinischen Bericht abkürzen?

Tags: meaning

In einem Bericht habe ich gelesen, dass eine Patientin 5/d Stuhlgang hat. Das liest sich für mich wie 5 mal täglich. Gemeint war aber alle 5 Tage. Wie kann man das abkürzen, ohne falsch verstanden zu werden?

Comment: Es ist zwar keine Abkürzung der Phrase "alle fünf Tage", aber die Abkürzung 5-tgl. (oder 5-tägl.) gibt es. Das führt aber womöglich zu Missverständnisse, da sie der Abkürzung 5x tgl. sehr ähnlich ist.

Comment: vielleicht so:  a.5T

Answer (score 3):

Mathematisch wäre *1/5d* richtig, in etwas klarerer Schreibweise *1/(5d)*. Aber ob das verstanden wird?

Comment: 0 0 */5 in crontab Notation. :)

Answer (score 2):

6/Mt

= 6 mal pro Monat
= 6 mal in 30 Tagen, macht ca. alle 5 Tage

(Ich glaube zwar, sie geht 5 mal am Tag ...)

Comment: Diese Antwort finde ich super: Kreativ, korrekt, kurz. Leider befürchte ich würde es dennoch Verwirrung stiften. Und zur Vollständigkeit: aus dem Kontext was ersichtlich, dass die Dame nicht oft genug den Darm leerte.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt keine sinnvolle Abkürzung für *alle 5 Tage* im Deutschen.

Answer (score 1):

Wie schon andere schrieben gibt es keine allgemeine Abkürzung für "alle x Tage", aber:

Eine Abkürzung ist immer dann verständlich, wenn sich Sender und beabsichtiger Empfänger über ihre Bedeutung einig sind. Dies schließt natürlich nicht aus, dass beide eine allgemein gebräuchliche oder bekannte Abkürzung benutzen, die dann auch für andere erkennbar ist.

Dementsprechend wäre etwa

> 5/d

in einem Krankenhaus oder einer Praxis in der sich alle über den Code einig sind eine eindeutige Aussage für *alle 5 Tage*. Während meinetwegen

> 5/tgl

für *5mal täglich* steht. Handelt es sich dagegen um eine Fallbeschreibung sollten entsprechende Erklärungen im Glossar/Anhang erklärt werden, falls sie nicht wie gesagt dem Zielpublikum bekannt sein sollten (aber selbst dann sollte man es eigentlich tun  oder allgemein verständliche Formulierungen wählen ^^).

Warum man solche Abkürzungen nutzt und sie nicht ausschreibt kann man ganz einfach mit Zeitersparnis begründen. So kommuniziert der Zahnarzt der notierenden Hilfe auch eher ein "13C" als ein "Karies im Eckzahn des rechten Oberkiefers". Dass der Patient da liegt und keine Ahnung hat was da vor sich geht interessiert auch erstmal nicht.

---

"Soll ich gegen meinen R05 lieber was mit d6 oder d12 nehmen?" "Du bölkst eh schon 24/7, nimm doch einen W20 und lass den Zufall entscheiden."